# pymongo - bson.errors.InvalidDocument raised only sometimes for no apparent reason

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

my documents look like this : `{ "_id" : 5, "hunger" : 5, "energy" : 50 }`

I'm calling this function..

```
def getEnergy(_id) -> int:
    record = db.systems.find({"_id":_id}) # systems is the collection
    return record[0]['energy']
```

and getting this error..

```
  (...)
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 692, in __getitem__
    for doc in clone:
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1238, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1155, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1044, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1424, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1525, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, secondary_ok)
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1420, in _cmd
    return server.run_operation(
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 98, in run_operation
    message = operation.get_message(
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 351, in get_message
    request_id, msg, size, _ = _op_msg(
  File "C:\Users\mateo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 743, in _op_msg
    return _op_msg_uncompressed(
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000021E52535670>, of type: <class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>
```

Sometimes the function works just fine, and sometimes it throws an error. It seems to be a problem with the server but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: `record` is a _cursor_. of returned documents from the `find`. What if there is no match and no documents are returned from the `find`?

Comment: @prasad_ That document is always there in the database.

Comment: Since you are querying by `_id` field, you should use [find_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one).  `find_one` returns a _document_ or _None_. So, after the read, check for `None` and then use the document.

Comment: @prasad_ Noted. I'm still getting an error though. Also, there's no point checking for `None` as the document is always there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is in that function (which we can't 100% tell as you've only posted half the stack trace), you will get this error is you are passing a cursor into the function; this snippet reproduces the error:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

def getEnergy(_id) -> int:
    record = db.systems.find({"_id":_id}) # systems is the collection
    return record[0]['energy']

foo = db.somecollection.find()
getEnergy(foo)
```

error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000019DB0A0B070>, of type: <class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>
```

You need to examine where you are calling `getExport()` and check the parameter you are passing in isn't a cursor object.